# Finding the last digit of a very large 2^n number

Tags: c++, digit

As the title sais, i want to find the last digit of an 2^n number.

I know that it's about repetition of even numbers, but i don't know how to make it happen.

This is what I did:

```
return (2*ascii%10)%10 - 2;
```

But it's not the correct method

For example:

I got 2^97, find the last digit of this very large number.
Thank you!

Comment: Show some effort or ask a mathematician for a clever method.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Comment: Find a pattern [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two#The_first_96_powers_of_two).

Comment: The cycle goes: 2 => 4 => 8 => 6 => 2  (and continues that way). Think how to calculate the result for any other power

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Powers of 2:

```
2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256...
```

Last digits:

```
2, 4, 8, 6, 2, 4, 8, 6...
```

Last digit of 2^i is:

```
int arr[4] = {2, 4, 8, 6};
return arr[(i-1)%4];
```

Comment: Can you prove it's right?

Comment: It's pretty self evident. The last digit of 2^i is only determined by the last digit of 2^(i-1). Once a cycle is encountered it will continue forever.

Comment: Still not a strict proof. But at least a good hint. I mean currently the answer has no value, at least to me. If it was so obvious OP would not have any trouble figuring it out =).

Comment: It's a simple induction proof. Try it :)

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I know how to do it, but you are answering the question... I am just saying that giving away code with zero explanation has very little value, obviously OP couldn't do it. Though, at least the hint you gave was nice. I am not saying it's incorrect, just not very educational =)

Comment: The OP is not asking for a demonstration, just a solution. I don't like this kind of questions but honestly he doesn't have to proof anything to anybody, is a right answer, period.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that ld(x) means last digit of x. We got:

ld( pow( 2, 1 ) ) = 2

ld( pow( 2, 2 ) ) = 4

ld( pow( 2, 3 ) ) = 8

ld( pow( 2, 4 ) ) = 6

ld( pow( 2, 5 ) ) = 2

See a pattern here? There is one: if the exponent equals:

( multiple of 4 ) + 1 you got ld(x) == 2

( multiple of 4 ) + 2 you got ld(x) == 4

( multiple of 4 ) + 3 you got ld(x) == 8

( multiple of 4 ) + 0 you got ld(x) == 6

In C/C++ you can do it like that:

```
int lastDigit;
if ( exp == 0 )
    lastDigit = 1; // special case
int rem = exp % 4;
switch ( rem )
{
    case 1: lastDigit = 2;break;
    case 2: lastDigit = 4;break;
    case 3: lastDigit = 8;break;
    case 0: lastDigit = 6;break;
}
```

Comment: I think you meant exp == 0 in the special case. And you have to return afterwords. Also the switch has to be on rem+1 not rem.

Comment: Yeah, it was exp == 0; thanks for pointing it out. As for rem + 1, I don't think that is correct.